# Multiplicities of zeros of the zeta function

Tags: analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta

It is well known that if $\rho$ is a nontrivial zero of $\zeta(s)$ then so are $1-\rho$, $\bar{\rho}$, and $1-\bar{\rho}$. My question is: do these four zeros necessarily have the same multiplicity?

I know that it is unknown, but widely believed, that all zeros of $\zeta$ are simple, but given a nontrivial zero $\rho$, with multiplicity $n$, are the multiplicities of $1-\rho$, $\bar{\rho}$, and $1-\bar{\rho}$ also $n$?

I read an article stating that it has been shown that $\zeta'(s)\neq0$ when $\Re(s)<1/2$, which would immediately answer my question with a "no," but I also saw in a different article that $\zeta'$ having any zeros on the left side of the critical line $s=1/2$ would imply the Riemann Hypothesis, so if that's the case then it is still unverified and does not answer my question.

Comment: yes of course they have the same multiplicities (the local form of an analytic function with real coefficients implies this for $\rho, \bar \rho$ and the functional equation implies this for $\rho, 1-\rho$); note that the existence of zeroes of the derivative with $0<\Re s <1/2$ implies the falsity of RH not its truth

Comment: The fact that those four zeros are all zeros follows from a much stronger fact—the symmetries of the global function $\zeta(s)$ itself. Those symmetries further imply that the multiplicities must be the same.

Comment: The analogue for the Dirichlet $L$-function of a nontrivial character $\chi$ would be that if $\rho$ is a nontrivial zero of $L(s,\chi)$ with multiplicity $m$ then $1-\overline{\rho}$ is a zero of $L(s,\chi)$ with multiplicity $m$, and $\overline{\rho}$ and $1 - \rho$ are zeros of $L(s,\overline{\chi})$ with multiplicity $m$.